# render partial with local variable in js.erb file - unexpected =>, expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following file. Displaying error:

```
SyntaxError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/responses/destroy.js.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')'
....append=( j render (:partial => "projects/new_response", :lo...
```

I cant found, what wrong with code?

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$('.responses').replaceWith('<%= j render (:partial => "projects/new_response", :locals => { project: @project } )%> ');
```

How write correct?

Comment: Can you try 1) removing the space after render here: render (:partial ...) or 2, leave the space, but remove the brackets around (:partial => ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space here:

```
#     |-  HERE
render(:partial =>
```

Or, surround your `j` method call params. Basically, Ruby can't figure out which is whose params when you have hash in your arguments list:

```
j(render (:partial =>  ...) )
```